# Is there any way I can update macOS to Catalina after I used ignore command in terminal

Tags: catalina

I used this command

```
sudo softwareupdate --ignore "macOS Catalina"
```

Now, it is not showing any update, nor downloading from app store. How can I fix this issue to update to macOS catalina.

Answer (score 2):

You can undo the command with

```
sudo softwareupdate --reset-ignored
```

You should also be able to use

```
sudo softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer
```

to get the Catalina installer.

See also https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/10/15/catalina-software-update-can-download-old-installers/